# What is the use of "As" in react when importing components?

Tags: reactjs

I saw this line of code

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

and I couldn't help but wonder why BrowserRouter is imported "Router". Why not just use the name as it is. What is the advantage of using the above method?

Comment: Using `as` simply [renames the import into an alias of your reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias) (shorter, more readable, or any other reasons). You can even do `import { BrowserRouter as BR }` and then simply use `<BR>` in your JSX template. The only _advantage_ is that you can name it whatever you want, no matter how it is named by the author(s) of the package/dependency.

Comment: "Of your preference", that's what I wanted to write ;)